# layout_alignParentEnd inside layout_alignParentEnd not working as expected

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

Suppose the scenario when we have a view end aligned and we need a view inside this one also end aligned. I used `layout_alignParentEnd` into both of them, but it extends first view like `match_parent` although it's `wrap_content`:

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/zone_controls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_more_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_more_options" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Expected:

[image]

I get:

[image]

Comment: use android:layout_alignParentRight="true" in imagebutton if you want to support below api 17. android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" work only above >api 17.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH same result, even if I changed both to `android:layout_alignParentEnd`

Answer (score -1):

Remove `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"` in your `ImageButton`, because its parent it's already end aligned:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/zone_controls"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="@color/primary_dark">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_more_options"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_more_options" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This code is a sample, in real code there are some other views inside `zone_controls` and I need `btn_more_options` to be end aligned.

Comment: Post the entire code then. Or you can use a ConstraintLayout instead of 2 RelativeLayouts